# my windows pc is not booting,cannot reinstall windows - is this because of mobo or HDD

Tags: hard-drive

I need help .Since Ten days back one of my windows pc (os 8.1 x64) won't boot. The computer shut down(BSOD occured) suddenly when I was browsing . After that i showed " Reboot And Select Proper Boot Device " . I saw the bios settings whether HDD is set to be the primary boot device but i didn't found it .Also in the bios i saw no hard drive detected .Two days later i cleaned dust inside the CPU , took out my 2 ram sticks and inserted them.After that i started the PC and it worked fine . Some of the files were not backed up.So I started backing up. But i was very busy that day and i shut down my pc and left my room .They next day I switched on the Pc and started acking up . But again BSOD occured . i was unable to see BSOD messages as auto restart was enabled by default.After that i have not been able to start the PC .Every time with normal boot or safe mode BSOD will occur. Still some of my docs and downloads were not backed up. I have decent sort of knowledge in software but i am very bad dealing with hardware faults.I called one of my friends who have repaired a lot of windows pc. We didn't try any linus cd. But we tried to boot from genuine W8.1 and even W7 cd s.Every time during installation the PC froze. During initial attempts the partitions showed but after that it disn't show. We have changed both the ram sticks,tried booting with only one stick ,changed DVD/CD writer but nothing worked . What can be the problem - the mobo or the hard drive .I am very angry with myself. Some files still not backed up.I am cursing myself

I took the drive to another pc and it was not recognised.Should i change the hard drive or the mobo ( power was reaching all components).Is there any great software to recover the HDD

The day before the Pc stopped functioning I was downloading a p2p file(i don't download torrents often) .I was constantly getting "Write to disk error.Access denied". However i scanned it with EIS,mbam and zemana and everything was fine .Please suggest me what to do . Please help me to sort it out

Comment: Can't be 100% sure with the given info, but I'm fairly confident in saying the hard drive is the problem.

Comment: how will i recover the data mate ?

Comment: The million dollar question... Hard to say, if it's valuable enough then send it in to a service and don't mess with it yourself but it will be expensive. Otherwise pop it in a USB enclosure and try standard data recovery methods (ddrescue, Recuva, Wise, etc).

Comment: Short answer : HDD is malfunctioning.

Answer (score 1):

Agree that it appears to be a hard drive problem. Also agree that it makes sense to eliminate the mobo by booting on a known good drive and running hw diagnostics.

One thing you might try is to clone your problem drive using a standalone solution such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IKC14OG). It might be a bit less fussy about minor drive errors that would otherwise cause a BSOD. You might get lucky, and if not you'll still have a useful device for hot-swapping bare drives.

Comment: Thank you for posting a clear, concise answer with both a diagnosis and a recommended course of action. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

It sure seems like the hard drive is bad, but your are all over the place with your troubleshooting. The one thing you didn't do was test the PC without the suspect hard drive.

To determine if the issue is the motherboard, or memory, remove the hard drive in question. Connect a known working drive and attempt to run hardware diagnostics. If things work as they should, it will point to the original drive being bad.

That is my guess since it was not recognized by another PC. If your data is critical, I suggest you start investigating a data recovery service to retrieve it.